# How to specify which characters are allowed in a textbox with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, textfield

http://jsfiddle.net/WhP8q/

I'm trying to restrict input to alpha numeric, 0-9, A-Z,a-z.

The ASCII table i'm referencing: http://www.asciitable.com/
Here is what I have so far

```
$(function() {
    $("input").bind("keydown paste", function(e) {
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        var c = code;
        var letterAllowed = ((c > 47 && c < 58) || (c > 64 && c < 90) || (c > 96 && c < 123))
        if (code > 32 && !letterAllowed) {
            return false;
        }
    });
});​
```

right now, the tilde (~) character is prevented from getting input into the field, but other special / shift characters such as !@#$% all get entered into the text field.
I'm pretty sure my logic is sound, but my issue is with some misunderstanding of javascript bindings? idk

Comment: Uhm, you mean that you have a problem with the `paste` event? If so, did you think of the fact that `keydown` is for a single character and `paste` can be for multiple characters?

Comment: keyCode refers to the key that is pressed, not the character that it will input. The shift characters are a combination of the Shift keyCode and the key that is pressed. To see this in action, go to http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

Comment: refer:
http://jsfiddle.net/lesson8/HkEuf/1/

you can add code number for alphabets in the above code.

or 

try this..
http://jsfiddle.net/DHCUg/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preventing character input for only some cases is very complicated in javascript, as in the [`keypress` event](http://quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html) (the one you'd want to prevent) you do not know the afterwards `value` of your input, but only the [`keycode`](http://quirksmode.org/js/keys.html) of the pressed key (and not even the resulting char for sure). Also, you will need to care about special keys like  or .

I'd recommend something like this:

```
$("input").on("keypress keyup paste", function(e) {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In case of restrict the character you enter, You can replace the character which is not alphanumberic.

```
<input type='text' id="txtAlphaNumeric"/>
<input type='text' id="txtNumeric"/>
<input type='text' id="txtAlphabet"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#txtNumeric').keyup(function() {
        if (this.value.match(/[^0-9]/g)) {
            this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
        }
    });
    $('#txtAlphabet').keyup(function() {
        if (this.value.match(/[^a-zA-Z]/g)) {
            this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, '');
        }
    });
    $('#txtAlphaNumeric').keyup(function() {
        if (this.value.match(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g)) {
            this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer taken from: [jquery allow only alphanumeric](http://4rapiddev.com/javascript/jquery-allow-only-numeric-characters-or-only-alphabet-characters-in-textbox/)

Comment: Why the absolutely unnecessary if-statement?

Comment: Also, hooking only on `keyup` leads to flickering and not detecting pastes etc.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, I need to do the following:

```
$("input").keypress(function(e){
        var code = e.charCode;
```

charCode will give the actual character code of the typed letter, rather than the ascii code of the last pressed key

see http://api.jquery.com/keypress/